# Touch screen and cold, dry fingers

Tags: cellphone, touchscreen

I've noticed that when I pick up my smartphone first thing after waking up, the touch screen is not very accurate in picking up my "clicks" and gestures.  I'm speculating that it's got something to do with the fact that my fingers are colder and dryer than normal when I've just woken up.

Can anyone confirm or debunk my speculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most touch screens are capacitive - meaning they detect the change in capacitance that is introduced by touching them. Insulators generally do not introduce a large enough change in capacitance to trigger the touch screen. So if your fingers are turning to papery stumps somehow, you wont be able to trigger it. This has nothing to do with the temperature of your fingers, but everything to do with the moisture and oil content on the surface.

Comment: Thanks, that also explains why it also doesn't work well if there's excess moisture on my fingers, such that I leave any kind of trail from touching the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Actually depending on the touchscreen construction, there can be very significant thermal effects.  Heat or cold fingers/objects can leave a signal residue in the panel relative to it's neighbors that absolutely can impact your touchscreen performance.